# Send slider value from python to Ableton Live

Tags: python, midi

I want to send to Ableton Live float number that will set the instrument parameter from code (python). I try to edit midi remove script (no documentation and not worked). I can send note tone and velocity through MIDI and it works, but i can't send slider or knob value.

MIDI example:

```
import time
import rtmidi
midiout = rtmidi.MidiOut()
available_ports = midiout.get_ports()
if available_ports:
    midiout.open_port(0)
else:
    midiout.open_virtual_port("My virtual output")
note_on = [0x90, 60, 112] # channel 1, middle C, velocity 112
note_off = [0x80, 60, 0]
midiout.send_message(note_on)
time.sleep(0.5)
midiout.send_message(note_off)
del midiout
```

Comment: You'll need to show the code where you're trying to send the controller values, and give a better description of what's not happening.